# How can I move an img under background

Tags: background, fade, loader

I have this code:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/loader.gif" alt="<?php echo ANSIMUZ_THEME; ?>" />
```

How can I move loader.gif under main background? (so it will show up before main background and hides when background is loaded)
main background is somewhere maybe here:

```
$('#home-title').backstretch([
myJsVars.front_background1
```

I dont really know java

Comment: I know some Java, and i definitely see no Java in your examples code. This is Javascript, right? Entirely different than Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use pure css z-index to set the hierarchy.
Make sure the loader image has a lower z-index than #home-title.
Like this:

```
#home-title {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

img#loader {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Don't forget add the id attribute **id="loader"** on your loader image element.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...may be help ful to you

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.image_loader').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

```css
.main{
 position:relative;
}
.image_loader{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:10;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100px;
}
.background_image{
 
 z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
 <img class="background_image" src="http://placehold.it/700" alt="background" />
 <img class="image_loader" src="http://oi57.tinypic.com/2rww2gz.jpg" alt="loader" />
    
</div>
```